# jQuery detach IE issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

For tab persistence in Backbone, I am saving the backbone view for that tab (say tab1) and detaching it from DOM. Later when the user comes back to the tab1 the saved view is rendered.

I am saving the page state i.e. the backbone view as -

```
this.pageState = $(this.bodyContainer.$el.find(".pageContent"));
$(this.bodyContainer.$el.find(".pageContent")).detach();
```

This works perfectly on ff and chrome but for IE I have to do the following work around for IE -

```
if($.browser.msie)
  this.pageState = $(this.bodyContainer.$el.find(".pageContent")).clone();
else
  this.pageState = $(this.bodyContainer.$el.find(".pageContent"));

$(this.bodyContainer.$el.find(".pageContent")).detach();
```

Is there a jQuery detach issue for IE? Is there a better way to copy view that works for all browsers?

Comment: You've not described the issue so I really don't know what the solution is, but how about just always using `.clone()`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is awesome or not:

```
var pageStateElem = $(this.bodyContainer.$el.find(".pageContent"));

this.pageState = $.browser.msie ? pageStateElem.clone() : pageStateElem;

pageStateElem.detach();
```

I only removed some of the repetition from your code.  :-p